# Twitter Bootstrap 2.x: How to get top corner of Container to line up with Header corner?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone have any tips or advice on how I can get the top corner of my container background graphic to line up to the left corner of my header? *Ignore the brownish color for now..I'm just concerned about getting the placement correct at the moment.*

**Here's a [screenshot of the offending area](http://www.ogmda.com/test/img/corner.jpg).
Here's a [live preview of my page](http://ogmda.com/test/).**

**Note:** I'm using a grid system and that is the reason why I have that extra left margin.

Comment: Start removing the style `.container` -> `margin-top: 2em;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the default grid, see also http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem.
The grid is 940 px width.
The width of the `.container` class is also 940px.
The `.row` class got a width of 940px too. But the `.row` class got a negative left margin of -20px. The total width of the `.row` will be 940px + 20px = 960px.
You add the background-image of the header to a `.container` (940px) and the black background color to a `.row` (960px).

**solution 1** (preferred):

Wrap your content in divs with the `span*` class. B.e. the width of a div.span12 is 940px.

```
<div class="container">
    <header class="row homePage">
        <div style="background-color: #1C0F0A;" class="span12"> 
            <nav class="clearfix" id="homeNav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="span2" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="span2" href="menu.html">Our Menu</a></li>
                    <li class="span3"></li>
                    <li><a class="span2" href="#">Experience</a></li>
                    <li><a class="span2" href="#">Location</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to remove the background-color of header.row, section.row in your css.

**solution 2**

Put your background-image in a (div).row:

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row headerrow"></div>
<header class="row homePage">
```

css:

```
.container .headerrow {
    background-image: url("../img/container_top.png");
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Remove `.homePage {
    margin-top: 0.7em;
}` from you custom.css too.